# Is Ezra Bridger based on Aladdin?

Tags: star-wars, disney, star-wars-rebels, aladdin, character-similarity

(Mild spoilers below!)

In the TV show *Star Wars: Rebels* we meet a protagonist named Ezra Bridger.

[image: Ezra Bridger vs Aladdin]

His physical appearance is strikingly similar to that of Aladdin: they both have similar hairdos, hair color, nose shape, complexion etc.

Beside their *appearance*, they even share similar character traits and bios:
Both are poor orphans who have resorted to marketplace thievery and such to survive. Both then discover they have access to magical powers. Aladdin has

> a Genie.

while Ezra has

> the Force.

In the pilot episode/movie for *Rebels* they even call Ezra a "street rat", which is something Aladdin is famously know as.

Their personalities are also similar. They both can often be seen wear a smirk on their face (as seen in the image above).

#### Is there any evidence showing that the **creators** of *Star Wars: Rebels* **based** Ezra Bridger on Aladdin? If so, why?

Comment: That's the first thing which came to my mind after I saw him in the first episode.

Comment: And so the Disneyfication of Star Wars continues, and I love it!

Comment: "Street rat?" I don't buy that.

Comment: Technically, since Star Wars takes place a long time ago, wouldn't it be more logical for Aladdin to be based on Ezra?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**No, the creators claim that Aladdin wasn't an intentional influence.**

[image: Amy Ratcliffe Tweet]

*Rebels* creator Dave Filoni spoke on a panel at the April 2015 Star Wars Celebration Anaheim and said the comparison is [flattering but unintentional.](http://www.sirstevesguide.com/2015/04/18/star-wars-rebels-season-two-press-conference/)

Ralph Macchio is an actor best known for starring in the Karate Kid film series.

[image]

The Aladdin comparison is definitely widely made, though, and Ezra was at least in part designed to evoke a Middle Eastern origin.

> “One of the things we did say consciously was that there was a biblical sense to the naming and to sort of seriousness of purpose of the original movies." 
>    <sub>- Creator Simon Kinberg in an [interview on starwars.com](http://www.starwars.com/news/star-wars-rebels-whats-in-a-name)</sub>

Comment: Thanks. apparently [Amy Ratcliffe](http://www.starwars.com/news/contributor/aratcliffe) is a writer who contributes to various outlets including Nerdist, IGN, and Star Wars Insider.

Comment: Yep, Amy has interviewed the creators on many occasions, and the second hyperlink is to a second summary of the Rebels panel that also mentions the Aladdin thing. Sorry for the lack of links in the original post - I'm new and didn't have enough reputation to link more than 2 sources!